# Django: Model with managed = False automatically includes id in return query

Tags: django

I have a queryset based on a Model that has managed = False in the meta, and django is automatically adding an id field to the queryset even when not included in the .values() list.

```
class GenerateTimeSeriesOuterModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'GenerateTimeSeriesOuterModel'
        app_label = 'GenerateTimeSeriesOuterModel'
        managed = False

    # Used by TableSubquery(BaseTable): class in Subquery.py to generate 'from (subquery)'
    subquery = None

    objects = SubqueryManager()
```

The model has the managed flag set to False, and uses a custom manager. When I try to do something like this:

```
GenerateTimeSeriesOuterModel.objects.all().set_subquery(some_subquery).annotate(
    'foo_bar': F('foo_bar')
).values('foo_bar')
```

This returns the following query:

```
select
    subquery.id,
    subquery.foo_bar
from (
    select something as foo_bar from some_table
) as subquery
```

as you can see id is added automatically but does not exist from the subquery so it throws an error. Any thoughts on removing the id?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table behind this model?

Comment: There isn't a primary key for this model, it's not a db table but a holder for a subquery. It's used to generate the following SQL 'select * from (some_subquery)', so it's not based on a real db table, but the SQL from the subquery. That's why I use the managed = False flag

Comment: a model always has a primary key. If you do not specify one, Django automatically adds one with the name `id`.

Comment: Well that's fine if the model auto generates one, I'd just like to not select the ID during the queryset. The real issues comes from .values('foo_bar') produces 'select id, foo_bar'. I only want to select foo_bar